# Paypal integration back-end?

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to store the clients credit card information on our secure website database and automatically pass the values to paypal to process without even having to show paypal website?

I would like to do this so client does not have to enter paypal credit card information each time for payment, if they do not want to setup a paypal account.

So basically just use the paypal system in the back-end.  After the information is passed to paypal, it processes it, and redirects user to another page.

Update: Paypal Introducing Direct Payment

Can I just pass credit card information from my secure web database to direct payment system, and have it be processed without manually entering data?

Comment: to store cc info on your website, your company need to pass to many rules and regulations in order to store cc info  on your server.... ref: https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/pci-compliance-basics-for-credit-card-security

Answer (score 0):

It is never recommended to store credit card details in your database for a number of reasons.  You really don't need to, either.

Instead, you can use PayPal's [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) API.

> The DoReferenceTransaction API operation processes a payment from a
>   buyer's account, which is identified by a previous transaction.

Basically, you just pass in the transaction ID of a previous sale or authorization transaction along with a new amount to be charged.  PayPal will charge the card using the details they have saved in their system, so you don't have to worry about the hassle of protecting sensitive data like that.

Comment: What if they decide to use a different credit card, will this still work?

Comment: No, it would use the same card they used in the previous transaction.  If they want to use a different one they'd have to re-enter it regardless of how you process it.

Comment: That said, if they happen to make 2 separate purchases from you with separate cards then you could use DRT with whichever transaction ID is associated with the card they want to use in the future.

Comment: So basically, if I send them an invoice, they click pay now button, and get to paypal forms fields and enter credit card info.  After this transaction completes, if I send them another invoice, when they click pay now button, it will take them to a screen to choose to add a new credit card, or check box an option for using the last credit card transaction info?

Comment: No.  Now you're talking PayPal Invoicing, which is completely separate from DoDirectPayment (which I assumed you were referring to when you said direct payment in the original post.)

Comment: I am not using paypal invoicing, but creating my own invoice, but just using paypal payment processing.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57637/discussion-between-user1929393-and-andrew-angell).